# Temporarily disable screensaver on Windows 10 in an easy way

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

Pretty simple issue - I work on something, I need the screen to stay on all the time until I'm done. I do not want the screensaver to intrude upon my work. While working, I do not touch the keyboard or mouse, but I do need to look at the screen. I'm just using the browser, which does not disable the screensaver.

The screensaver is set to start after 10 minutes of activity, and require a password to unlock - which would be very intrusive when I'm in the middle of something.

On macOS this would be trivial: set up a hot corner, assign to it "disable screensaver", and move the mouse to that corner for the duration of the work. When done, just move the mouse out of that corner.

Is there a way to accomplish something equally simple on Windows?

Comment: Set your screen saver not to lock the Computer and then that solves this issue. Ctrl-Alt-Del and Lock whenever you need to lock.  Check your BIOS and Power Drivers because actually using a Browser should stop the screen saver from kicking in.

Comment: "Set your screen saver not to lock the Computer" - not acceptable.

Comment: Then fix the drivers as I mentioned because using a Browser on a properly operating machine will prevent the screen saver from kicking in.

Comment: Not enough. I am looking for a general solution, independent of usage patterns. "Hey, operating system, disable the screensaver until I tell you to stop." The macOS hot corners are the perfect example.

Comment: Setting the screensaver to do what you want whenever you want at random times will be much harder than anything I proposed. Too many difficult situations. I do what you want daily with no issues.

Comment: @FlorinAndrel - What do you mean it’s not acceptable to temporarily disable that feature?  You are literally asking for us a way to disable it?

Comment: But that feature of corners was removed after Windows 95 (so 25 years ago) Plus! Pack was removed.

Comment: Use a 3rd-party tool such as Caffeine or Don't Sleep.

Comment: In earlier versions of Windows you just left the cursor over the Start button, but I don't think that works any more.

Comment: Is this a work computer? Is the screen saver timeout set by domain policy?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Store has the app "Keep Screen On".

https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N7QSCS3LWFS

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the *Awake* extension of **PowerToys**.
First make sure you enable it on the app main menu, and then a blue cup icon should show up in the taskbar [hidden icons drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wp30.png), which you can right click to choose your preferred method.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but it does not appear to do anything about the screensaver actually. The screensaver will kick in regardless of how I setup Awake. Perhaps Awake is only designed to deal with the power plan (e.g. when the screen is actually turned off by the system)?

Comment: Oh, really? It does deactivate the screensaver in my case. What screensaver configuration are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/26175

Answer (score 0):

Not for the screensaver, but in "Power & Sleep" the setting "Screen: when plugged in, turn off after" turns off the screen after a given number of minutes. Here is a powershell script that sets this feature to "Never", runs the DeaDBeeF audio player and waits, finally restores the old setting after the audio player exits.

A desktop shortcut launches it with the following target:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -windowstyle hidden -command &'C:\MyUtils\ScreenSaverSet.ps1'
```

You could run a browser instead of the audio player or run nothing and pause for the user to hit any key when powering off the screen becomes desirable again.

Note that running of powershell scripts is controlled by a policy which is off by default. Google how to turn it on or put the following in a batch file *ScreenSaverSet.bat* and run that instead which theoretically bypasses the policy.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\MyUtils\ScreenSaverSet.ps1
```

Script follows:

```
#Get GUID of active plan
#$GUID = (((Get-CimInstance -classname Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace "root\cimv2\power" | where {$_.IsActive -eq "true"}).InstanceID) -split("\\"))[1]
#Cut {} off of string at beginning and end of GUID
#$GUID = $GUID.Substring(1, $GUID.Length-2)

#The original script getting the GUID only worked as admin so use this method instead
$powerScheme = powercfg -getactivescheme
$GUID = $powerScheme.Substring($powerScheme.IndexOf(":")+2)
$GUID = $GUID.Substring(0, $GUID.IndexOf(" "))
#Write-Host "GUID = ""$GUID"""

#Get a list of all options for this plan
$Options = powercfg -query $GUID SUB_VIDEO VIDEOIDLE
$index = 0

#Find index of line that contains Turn off screen Settings
For($i=0; $i -lt $Options.Length; $i++)
{
    $line = $Options[$i]
    if($line.ToLower() -like "*Turn off display after*")
    {
        $index = $i

        break
    }        
}

#AC Setting is 6 lines later
$screenOffSetting = $Options[$index + 6]
#trim off the beginning of the string, leaving only the value
$screenOffSettingTrimmed = $screenOffSetting.Substring($screenOffSetting.IndexOf(":")+2)
$screenOffSetting = [int]$screenOffSettingTrimmed / 60 # convert to minutes

# prevent screen turn off , run our program & wait, restore screen turn off
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\DeaDBeeF\deadbeef.exe" -Wait
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac $screenOffSetting
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [HotCornersApp](https://sites.google.com/site/bytecar/home/hotcornersapp), which enables 'hot corners', just like you can easily do on a Mac.